# How to add dynamic dropdown to template without changing model?

Tags: ember.js

So I had a route: `/tournaments/setup/:tournament_id` in my ember app, and it displayed various fields from a model.

But then I find that I'll need other models on the same page. For example, suppose I want the list of all players, so that I can make a dropdown for selecting players to join a tournament.

I can pass an object:

```
this.transitionTo('tournaments.setup', {tournament: tournament, players: players});
```

and that works once I change the handlebars template to reflect the change of context.

But now the URL is wrong. The URL is `/tournaments/setup/undefined`. I'm sure there is a way to explicitly handle this also, but I don't know what it is ...

... and I feel like I'm losing the path. Is there a more conventional way to do what I'm doing?

**Update:** I've found that I can get the URL to work by adding an id:

```
this.transitionTo('tournaments.setup', {id: tournament.id, tournament: tournament, players: players});
```

but I'm still wondering if I'm doing this the right way.

Comment: Try passing in the tournament object itself and let ember figure out the id.                              `this.transitionTo('tournaments.setup', tournament)`

Comment: How would I then have access to the players object? That's what I had been doing before I needed more data on that page.

Comment: You might need to override the serialize hook of the route to get the url right. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is load the models in your route and stick them in a controller to user them.  I usually do this in the `beforeModel` hook. So in your `App.TournamentsSetupRoute` do something like this:

```
App.TournamentSetupRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function() {
         var self = this;
         var players = this.store.find('player');
         players.then(function() {
             self.controllerFor('players').set('model',players);
         });
    }
});
```

So now, when ever this route is entered, the `players` will be fetched from your API and stored in a controller.  In your controller, just add the `players` controller to `needs` so you can access it.

```
App.TournamentSetupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   needs: ['players']
});
```

You can access the `players` models anywhere in your controller by doing `this.get('controllers.players.model);` and iterate over it in your template like so:

```
<select>
   {{#each player in controllers.players.model}}
       <option>{{player.name}}</option>
   {{/each}}
</select>
```

Hope that helps! I haven't tested the above code, so there may be a few typos, but it should help get ya there.